# AWS - Understanding DataTransfer

Tags: amazon-web-services

In my **AWS Billing & Cost Management Dashboard**, I can see under **DataTransfer->Bandwidth** this line:

**$0.010 per GB - regional data transfer - in/out/between EC2 AZs or using IPs or ELB**

This costs **~1500$ every month**. And I would like to understand what this means.
Nobody able to explain and AWS docs unfortunately do not understandable.

Could somebody please explain what is it?

My architecture is pretty simple:
Auto-scaled environment with a load balancer and one RDS database in multi-zone (AZ), S3 bucket for storage and CloudFront for static content delivery.

Thanks.

Comment: To confirm, the data transfer by itself is costing you $1500 every month? That's not your entire bill?

Comment: @MattHouser, Yes, you are right. The data transfer itself. Do you have an idea what is it?

Comment: What sort of explanation are you looking for?  The fact that you have an RDS database in multiple AZs, and the bill includes data transfers among AZs, seems pretty clear...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this kind of question are better addressed directly to the provider.

Answer (score 2):

This particular line item accounts for bandwidth costs which include:

- Data transfer between availability zones
- Data transfer within the same availablity zone, but using the public IP address instead of the private IP address
- Data running through your ELB

This includes data transfer:

- Between your EC2 instances
- From your ELB to your EC2 instances
- From your EC2 instances to your RDS instance

If your monthly cost for data transfer alone is $1,500.00, then that means you're transferring 150 TB of data between AZs and through your ELB.

If that amount of data seems high for your application, I would suggest talking to AWS support about it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Is it possible somehow to break down this parameters in AWS dashboard? So I can deeply understand exactly what costs what.

Comment: I am not aware of an AWS tool that can be used to break down this line item. If you have questions, best to contact AWS support.